# I'm getting "Fatal error: Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting!" error using glob(). why?

Tags: php, glob

```
function deletefiles($directory)
{
    $folder = glob($directory);  // <--error on this line.
    foreach($folder as $file)
    {
        if(is_dir($file)) 
        { 
            deletefiles($directory);
        } 
        else 
        {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
    if(is_dir($directory))
    {
        rmdir($directory);
    }
}
```

That's the code causing the error. The function is supposed to delete all files and subdirectories of a specified folder. Each folder only contains maybe 5 maximum subfolders.
This function worked when there was only files in the folder. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Out of interest; consider looking at the following php class [Recursivedirectoryiterator](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 places needed to fix.

```
function deletefiles($directory)
{
  $folder = glob($directory . '/*'); // <-- here
  foreach($folder as $file)
  {
    if(is_dir($file)) 
    { 
      deletefiles($file); // <-- and here
    } 
    else 
    {
      unlink($file);
    }
  }
  if(is_dir($directory))
  {
    rmdir($directory);
  }
}
```

Comment: Looks like xdazz was nice enough to give you the whole code. +1

Comment: Thanks so much. Can't believe i missed that. Worked perfect. wish i could give u a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending the function request with `$directory` rather than `$file` which means you are delving into the structure at all, you are just calling the same function many times over in the same folder.

I think you want to change the first `if` section to this:

```
if(is_dir($file)) 
{ 
    deletefiles($file);
}
```